# C# .NET: Using a PEM file with SignedXML to verify an Xml Signature

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature, pem, xml-signature

I am trying to validate and a `SignedXml` object that has been signed with a public key.  The public key is stored in a `.pem` file.  How can I verify the XML Signature using the pem File and .NET?

Can I easily use a `.pem` file or would it be better to use a `.pfx` file.  If so, how would I convert a `.pem` to a `.pfx`?

Conversely, is there a way to load the contents of a `.pem` file into a `X509Certificate2`?